# How do I increase the quota for a kub cluster in Qwiklabs Challenge?

Tags: quota

I'm doing the google cloud essentials challenge lab at the moment and have just attempted to create a kubernetes cluster as part of the challenge but receive the following error:

(gcloud.container.clusters.create) ResponseError: code=403, message=Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "IN_USE_ADDRESSES": request requires '9.0' and is 
short '1.0'. project has a quota of '8.0' with '8.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=qwiklabs-gcp-01-ffd17c2
c1034.

When I go to the IAM -> Quota page I can see the following...

[Image of quota's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijR3v.png)

I'm new to all of this so would appreciate any support!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the error by replacing `--region us-east1` with `--zone us-east1-b`.

I suspect `gcloud container clusters create my-cluster --region us-east1` uses more IPs than the zone alternative.